# Need to manually regsiter user, send the password and retreive their user ID

Tags: multisite, email, password, signup

I'm writing a custom signup script for users to register with on my MU-setup.

One problem I'm having is that `wpmu_signup_user()` sends the password activation email but it doesn't return the user ID which I need for the rest of the script. - It's my understanding that this doesn't create the user account, just an entry in the "signup" table.

The other way I've tried is using `wp_create_user()` which returns the user ID I need (as it creates the user properly) but no email for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force add a MU user and activate them, and email them, this will do it. It's a slightly altered version of a piece of the code in user-new.php.

```
wpmu_signup_user( $new_user_login, $new_user_email, array( 'add_to_blog' => $blogid, 'new_role' => $role ) );
$key = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT activation_key FROM {$wpdb->signups} WHERE user_login = %s AND user_email = %s", $new_user_login, $new_user_email ) );
$ret = wpmu_activate_signup( $key );
```

The wpmu_activate_signup function will send the welcome email. And the $ret from wpmu_activate_signup is an array of several things, including the user_id in $ret['user_id'].

Obviously you'll need to fill in the user name, email, blogid, and role in the above code.

Comment: Other lines you need to add:
`add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', '__return_false' );`  to disable email verification, and `switch_to_blog($blogId)` to make sure the email the does go out ha the correct blog URL.

Answer (score 1):

Send the email yourself within your signup script with the [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function.